# Find $\int F.dr$ where $F= \frac{y i - x j}{x^{2}+y^{2}}$ and $C$ is the circular path $x^{2} + y^{2} = 1$ in cartesion coordinate system.

Tags: vector-analysis, line-integrals

Find $\int F.dr$ where $F= \frac{y i - x j}{x^{2}+y^{2}}$ and $C$ is the circular path $x^{2} + y^{2} = 1$ described in counter clockwise sense.

The formula for flux is $\int {F_1 dy - F_2 dx}$ where $$F_1 = \frac{y}{(x^{2}+y^{2})},$$ $$F_2 = \frac{-x}{x^{2} + y^{2}}$$
$$\int F.dr = \int (\frac{y}{x^{2}+y^{2}}dy - \frac{-x}{x^{2}+y^{2}}dx$$

$$=\int_{-1}^{1} ydy + xdx$$

$($since $(x^{2}+y^{2} = 1$ and in given circle both x and y vary from -1 to 1 $)$

so the flux I get is 
$2$ which is not right answer.

the right answer is $-2\pi$ which can be found by using polar coordinates and applying same formula of flux , i used in above method.

What is wrong with the method I applied to evaluate flux? How to find flux using cartesion coordinates?

Comment: Either your  bounds of integration are wrong or you don’t understand the parametrization you are using. It so bad I can’t tell what you are doing. Draw a picture.

Comment: Why would you put $\;-1,\,1\;$ as that integral's limits?? How does that refelct that you're trying to integrate over the unit canonical circle?

Comment: In given circle, limits of x and y are -1 to 1, so i put these limits.

Comment: If it's hard to understand what the OP means using the bounds they used, how can you answer it, @DonAntonio?  Just by guessing what was meant? Why not confirm that first with the asker?

Comment: @amWhy1 I wanted to solve the same question using cartesion coordinates.

Comment: @amWhy Apparently you didn't understand what I wrote, which is "it's hard to understand what you meant"...when he wrote all what he wrote in his *calculations* in the cartesian system. But he wrote he wanted the linear integral (the flux...even twice)  and that's easy. So: it's hard to understand what he meant with his calculations in that way, but it's easy how to do this as shown below.

Comment: Mathsaddict, you should include, *in your post*,  the information that you already solved the problem in terms of the parametarization of DonAntonio, but you have tried to do so also in Cartesian coordinates.

Comment: @Mathsaddict I added something to my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's hard to understand what you really meant, but first parametrize the unit canonical circle (positive direction):

$$r(t)=(\cos t,\,\sin t)\;,\;\;t\in[0,2\pi]\implies r'(t)=(-\sin t,\,\cos t)$$

so

$$\int_c\vec F\cdot d\vec r=\int_0^{2\pi}(\sin t,\,-\cos t)\cdot(-\sin t,\,\cos t)dt=\int_0^{2\pi}-dt=-2\pi$$

**In cartesian coordinates**:

With $\;y=\pm\sqrt{1-x^2}\;$ (upper and lower semicircle, resp.), we can do the parametrizations:

$$\begin{cases}r_1(x)=(x,\,\sqrt{1-x^2})\implies r_1'(x)=\left(1,\,-\frac x{\sqrt{1-x^2}}\right)\\{}\\
r_2(x)=(x,\,-\sqrt{1-x^2})\implies r_2'(x)=\left(1,\,\frac x{\sqrt{1-x^2}}\right)\end{cases}\;\;,\;\;\;-1\le x\le 1$$

and from here (be very careful with the direction!!):

$$\text{Over the upper semicircle $C_1$}: -\int_{C_1}\frac{\sqrt{1-x^2}}{x^2+y^2}dx-\frac x{x^2+y^2}dy =$$

$$=-\int_{-1}^1\left(\sqrt{1-x^2}+\frac{x^2}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}\right)\,dx=-\int_{-1}^1\frac{dx}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}=-\int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2}dt=-\pi$$

I'll let you try to complete the calculation on the lower semicircle.

Comment: I solved this question as you explained, and got the answer. Can't we solve the same problem in cartesion coordinate system?

Comment: Thanks, i understood the whole solution except one thing, why did you take negative sign for line integral in upper semi circle?

Comment: @Mathsaddict Yes, because when the parameter $\;x\;$ runs from $\;-1\;$ to $\;1\;$ , as defined, we run over the upper semicircle **clockwise**, whereas we want *counterclockwise*. That's why we need to multiply the line integral by $\;-1\;$ .

Answer (score 0):

The mistake comes from the fact that what you are trying to compute is not a flux (I believe that is called circulation in english). The formula for the (1-dim) flux is

$$
\Phi= \int_C \mathbf{F} \cdot \mathbf{n} d s
$$

where $\mathbf{n}$ is the unit vector **normal** to the curve $C$ pointing out, while $ds$ is the arclength on the curve $C$.

The above integral is clearly zero as $\mathbf{F}$ is **tangent** to the circle $C$.  By the way this also shows up in your calculation as $\int_{-1}^1 x dx =0$.

However what you are given is, presumably,

$$
\int_C \mathbf{F} \cdot \mathbf{dr} 
$$

where $\mathbf{dr}$ is the infinitesimal arclength times the unit **tangent** to the curve. 
In this case

$$
\mathbf{F} \cdot \mathbf{dr} = -\frac{1}{r} ds
$$

integrating this over $C$ you obtain $-2\pi$. This is essentially the derivation in polar coordinates